# How to create, reference and inject services / providers dynamically decided further in running program based on changing condition(s)?

Tags: javascript, nestjs

When looking at the NestJs documentation on [Custom Providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers), it appears that all the services and their referencing is pretty much predetermined in modules. These modules are pre-loaded when program starts running.

I am trying to figure out how to set up and use service classes dynamically based on conditions that arise while program is running and conditions change, than on that condition the program selects, loads, and executes the desired service/provider.

This documented example appears like a start, but is still pretty much based on initial config. values, not on dynamically produced values in the middle of a running app.

```
    const configServiceProvider = {
      provide: ConfigService,
      useClass:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
          ? DevelopmentConfigService
          : ProductionConfigService,
    };

    @Module({
      providers: [configServiceProvider],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

I can think of this arrangement:

```
export interface ServiceInterface {
    doStuff: Function,
    . . .
}

@Injectable()
export class AService implements ServiceInterface  {
 . . .
}

@Injectable()
export class BService implements ServiceInterface  {
 . . .
}

@Injectable()
export class CService implements ServiceInterface  {
 . . .
}



@Module({
  providers: [AService, BService, CService, ..., RunningService],
})
export class AppModule {}



@Injectable()
export class RunningService() {

  
  constructor(private serviceA: AService,
              private serviceB: BService, 
              private serviceC: CService, 
              . . . 
            ){}


  runningMethod() {

    . . .

    let chosenService: ServiceInterface;

    const condition: string = this.getCondition();

    switch (condition) {
      case 'A':
        this.chosenService = serviceA;
        break;
      case 'B':
        chosenService = serviceB;
        break;
      
      // etc
    }

    . . . 

    chosenService.doStuff();

  }
```

But this is very clunky and inflexible. Also, it still preloads all the predefined services, whether further needed or not.

Lets consider the scenario the programmer needs to choose and load only some of many services after a condition arises in a running code.

I would see it working like in Java or similar language, where you simply create an instance of class on demand. In NestJs DI this appears quite inflexible.

How to approach this scenario in the NestJs DI (dependency injection) system?